# Finding Limit of constant power nth term of sequence (this sequence converges)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let a be a positive real number and {$x_n$} be a sequence of rational numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$. Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{x_n}=1$

I know to solve this if $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ using bernoulli's inequality but how to solve it for $x_n$

My attempt (not correct)

Given 
$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$ ,
so for $\epsilon>0$
$|x_n-0| < \epsilon $ for all n>m

multiplying with $\log a$ on both sides, where a>1

therefore $\log a > 0$

$|x_n\log a-0| < \epsilon \log a $ for all n>m

$|\log a^{x_n}-0| < \log a^{\epsilon} $ for all n>m

but this stopped here..

Please Help

Answer (score 2):

$a^{x_n}=e^{x_nlog(a)}$, $lim x_nlog(a)=0$ implies the limit is $1$ since the function exponential is continuous.